# Write Terraform plan output in-memory rather than on a filesystem

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, terraform

I am developing an AWS Lambda function which uses a runtime of Python 3.8. The source code is packaged into a custom Docker image and then passed to the Lambda service.

In the Python program itself, I am executing various Terraform commands including "plan" and "show" using subprocess. I am writing the output of the plan to the /tmp directory using the "terraform plan -out=plan.txt" flag. Then, I convert the plan into JSON for processing using "terraform show -json plan.txt".

Since the plan file could contain sensitive data, I do not want to write it to the /tmp directory; rather I want to keep it in-memory to increase security. I have explored mounting tmpfs to /tmp which is not possible in this context. **How can I override the behavior of Terraform's "-out=" flag or create an in-memory filesystem in the container?**

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you create a Lambda to run terraform commands?

Comment: @MarkoE I want to execute "terraform plan" at-will in order to detect resource drift. Running Terraform inside of a Lambda does bring up interesting challenges, but this is the first one that has really been blocking.

Comment: And you can't use the CLI commands because...? :)

Comment: @MarkoE The Lambda will detect resource drift for several Terraform deployments and generate AWS Security Hub findings. The function is indeed running the Terraform CLI; it must be an automated solution and Lambda seemed like a good candidate as the platform. However, the application can be moved to run on EC2, ECS, EKS, etc.

Comment: If some of the variables/outputs are sensitive, you can mark them like that. They should be shown as `(sensitive)` in the plan output.

Comment: @MarkoE Agreed, the inputs and outputs of the Terraform code should be marked as sensitive. There are cases in which the resource attributes in the state or plan file can contain sensitive data, even with proper marking. The primary example of this is the aws_vpn_connection resource, which contains preshared keys in plaintext even with proper marking.
Because of cases like this as well as customer requirements, I am looking to keep any state files and plan files in memory.

Answer (score 0):

@msel, I guess you can take help of "terrahelp". Though I have not used it personally, I believe this could be really handy tool to handle sensitive data at plan level.

Something similar to below you need to do

```
terraform plan -out=plan.txt | terrahelp mask
```

You can read more about terrahelp here

https://github.com/opencredo/terrahelp

Reference : https://github.com/runatlantis/atlantis/issues/163

Comment: Thanks Tapan for your answer! Terrahelp looks interesting. In the example command you provided, it looks like terrahelp's input will be the stdout of the previous command. Instead, I want to deal with the output which currently goes to the filesystem because of "-out=plan.txt". 
In other words, "terraform plan -out=plan.txt" has two different outputs (one on stdout and one on the filesystem), and I am only concerned with the one on the filesystem.

Comment: @msel, Can't we write output of terraform plan command into some cache database like redis?

Comment: That is one option, but I'll need to override Terraform's behavior when specifying "-out=plan.txt" because it goes straight to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform itself can only write a saved plan file to something which behaves like a file. If you are on a Unix system then you may be able to exploit the "everything is a file" principle to trick Terraform to writing to something that isn't a file on disk, such as a pipe passed in from the parent process as an additional inherited file descriptor, but there is no built-in mechanism for doing so, and Terraform may require the filehandle to support system calls other than just `write` that are available for normal files, such as `seek`.

Comment: Martin, thanks for your response, I recognize your name from the official Terraform repo. I like your idea and I will research on how to implement it. It would be nice if Terraform could put a saved plan file on stdout so that I can easily pipe it in to the next command, but understandably there are very few people who would use this feature.

Comment: You might find this issue interesting: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/29778 . At the time I'm writing this there's nothing happening with it, but I that'll be where we'd share any updates about it.

Comment: Thank you, that is very interesting, and someone has provided a workaround which I can try.